# How to generate such view using Xcode 6.3 swift

Tags: xcode, swift

Im try to develop an to do list app, my problem is how to add/generate an image like button every time i add a new task.
Link to figure of explantion is shown below.
Your kind help with be much appriciated.
Links to any web tutorial, video or apple documentation is helpful.
My problem is how to display the view as in the figure and when i save a task how does a new image for the task will generate it self.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/czNmd.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V7n7.png

Comment: You can [embed pictures](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) in your question, use that rather than external links

Comment: I can't do so as i need to have 10 point to post an image. Thank you though for you concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you had a look at the Lister example that's on the iOS/Mac developer portals?

That pretty much does what you're looking for. All you need to do is design the layout of the tableview CellView as per how you need it.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014701

Coincidentally lister is a sort of task management productivity app.

Comment: 1st of all thank you for you reply, this is my first post. It is also my first step in learning iOS development. So, I'm a totally beginner here. I have seen your link but do you have a more visual link for a starter like me? Really appreciate your help. I am looking an UI collection view but i have no idea if it is the right choice. Your advice on it will be nice. Please and thank you...

Comment: You should be using a TableView rather than a collectionView.... Here's the sample code for the fundamentals of the UITableView: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318 . Also as you're new, have you looked into the MVC programming structure? It's pretty important and base-line stuff..

Comment: But isn't using TableView will produce a display with list of row? There is some one in the apple dev forum told me to use collection view. So, I'm confuse here. Lister, tableView or collectionView? Yes i had look into mvc. Btw, the documentation in sample code isn't much help to a beginner like me. I prefer a more visual tutorial. And i have use table view before.

Comment: A view based tableview displays a list of rows, each row containing tableCellVIEWS :)

Comment: owh ya...you have a point there...thanks a lot man...^_^

Comment: have a good look at the apple examples, both the iOS and OS X ones. The show you various ways of how to use the various controls, the API's and they use pretty much clean code :)  Hope it goes well! But just to re-iterate!! The lister example they have is a perfect sample go code that boasts the best of their coding :). From single tableView work all the way down to core-animation using Constraints :)